# How do I install KDE on Ubuntu server?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, vnc

I have Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (64 bit) server with no GUI. Can anyone tell me how do I install KDE on it? Will that command be okay?

```
apt-get install kubuntu-desktop -y
startx
```

Or something else has to be done?

Comment: Why don't you install kubuntu instead of installing KDE on ubuntu server?

Comment: I just dont want lol. I would like to install KDE on server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Most Ubuntu Server developers recommend not installing a GUI on a
>   server. There are multiple reasons for not installing a GUI.
>
> Some reasons to not install a GUI include:
>
> 1. You'll have more code subject to security vulnerabilities, more
>      packages that need updating, and more server downtime.
> 2. Performance may suffer because resources (memory, hard disk space,
>      CPU, etc.) will be consumed by the GUI.
> 3. It is best practice to only install needed software on a production
>      server.
> 4. The GUI may include other network services that are inappropriate
>      for a server.
>
> One of the goals of Ubuntu Desktop Edition is to make it easier for
>   users to use Linux. When installing some desktop environments,
>   services that you may not specifically want will be installed.
>
> For example avahi-daemon, which is used to help configure networking,
>   adds another open port and may introduce unwanted DNS conflicts with a
>   .local domain.
>
> If you're using an Ubuntu LTS release prior to 12.04 LTS, X11 and
>   desktop packages are not supported for the full 5 year lifecycle of
>   the LTS server release.
>
> So for the most secure server it is best to not install a
>   GUI.<sup>[Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI)</sup>

To go ahead, and install KDE, just type the command(s) below at the prompt:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

This will install all the default apps that comes with KDE.

If you just want the plain KDE desktop without any of the apps:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: How would I press ctrl+alt+t on server? it already starts with cli. will that command work?

Comment: I fixed that in the answer.  Sorry for the mishap.